# play framework 1.2.4 - Morphia 1.2.9 - _id type incorrect for batch insert

Tags: java, mongodb, module, playframework, morphia

According to the [play morphia documentation](http://www.playframework.org/modules/morphia-1.2.9/crud) you perform a batch insert using this syntax:

```
List<MyModel> myModels = ...;
MyModel.insert(myModels);
```

However whenever I do a batch insert the `_id` for the inserted rows is always a String hash:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50149be2d5522755b6f564ce"} , ...
```

I am expecting a `Long` by default as I have set `morphia.id.type=Long` in application.conf.
Inserting a row using a `.save()` gives me the expected result.

How can I perform a batch insert that uses the default `_id` type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an known issue on v1.2.9: https://github.com/greenlaw110/play-morphia/issues/89

The fix will enter the next release version.